# wildcard generics in HashSet constructor

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, hashset

The java `HashSet` implementation has a constructor:

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
}
```

Why it is `Collection<? extends E> c`? This isn't enough: `Collection<E> c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept here is called [*variance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) (covariance, contravariance).

Let's say you have the following two classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

In this case, you can say that *an instance of `B` is an instance of `A`*. In other words, the following code is perfectly valid:

```
A instance = new B();
```

Now, generic classes in Java are, by default, invariant. That means that a *`List<B>` is not a `List<A>`*. In other words, the following code will not compile:

```
List<A> as = new ArrayList<B>(); // error - Type mismatch!
```

However, if you have an instance of B, sure you can add it to a list of A (because B extends A):

```
List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
as.add(new B());
```

Now, let's say you have a method that deals with lists of A by consuming its instances:

```
void printAs(List<A> as) { ... }
```

It would be tempting to make the following call:

```
List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();
printAs(bs); // error!
```

However, it won't compile! If you want to make such a call work, you have to make sure that the argument, `List<B>`, is a subtype of the type expected by the method. This is done by using *covariance*:

```
void printAs2(List<? extends A> as) { ... }
List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();
printAs2(bs);
```

Now, this method takes an instance of `List<? extends A>`, and it is true that `List<B> extends List<? extends A>`, because `B extends A`. This is the concept of covariance.

---

After this introduction, we can go back to the constructor of HashSet you mention:

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) { ... }
```

What this means is that the following code will work:

```
HashSet<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();
HashSet<A> as = new HashSet<A>(bs);
```

It works because `HashSet<B> is a HashSet<? extends A>`.

If the constructor were declared as `HashSet(Collection<E> c)`, then the second line on the wouldn't compile, because, even if `HashSet<E> extends Collection<E>`, it is not true that `HashSet<B> extends HashSet<A>` (invariace).

Answer (score 2):

This is because when HashMap can contain and object that inherits from E, so you want to be able to pass a collection of objects of any type that inherits E, not just E.

If it were Collection, then you wouldn't be able to pass an `ArrayList<F>`, where F extends E, for example.